# Error 2755 when installing new program in windows 10

Tags: windows-10, permissions, windows-installer

I recently moved C:/Windows/Installer folder to another drive to save space and made a symbolic link, and now I am not able to install some programs(I tried installing blender it gives error 2755), but if I try to run the .msi file as an administrator from command prompt I am able to install blender (which I was able to install without running as admin)

Is there a way to solve the issue without running the .msi file as administrator everytime?
I suspect it is something related to permissions, but I am not sure what exactly is the problem.

Comment: There is no c:\windows\installer folder (Windows 10 Pro newest version and up)  .  What specific folder did you actually move?

Comment: @John There should be _(it's a hidden folder)_. [OP] In general, it's a bad idea to move system directories, especially out of `%WinDir%`, due to a range of reasons, one of which is the ACLs that protect directories like `%WinDir%\Installer`. There's also no guarantee that junction will hold up when the OS is reinstalled every six months _(every bi-annual update is effectively a Repair Install)_ or after a Windows Update - in general, `%WinDir%` and its subdirectories aren't intended to be modified/customized at the user level. I'm also unsure how `Dism` and `Sfc` would treat the junction

Comment: Good point. I see it in Tree Size.  OP - Do not move this specific folder or other "pieces" of Windows. Replan your space usage and install Windows to properly fit it.

Comment: OP:   Gutting Windows to save space is an Evergreen idea here. Nonetheless it is a very bad idea. Run Disk Cleanup (all items including System Files and let it delete Windows. old).  Then move documents to a different drive. That usually works.